# Usar <div> envés de <td> y <tr> para cargar datos

Tags: php, mysql

¿Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de cargar todos los registros de la base de datos en etiquetas div como se harian con los td y tr porque a mi me trae solo el ultimo registro?

```
            $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $contador = 0;

            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $codigo         = $fila['CODIGO'];
                $pais           = $fila['PAIS'];
                $ciudad         = $fila['CIUDAD'];
                $ruc            = $fila['RUC'];
                $rsocial        = $fila['RAZONSOCIAL'];
                $telefono       = $fila['TELEFONO'];
                $email          = $fila['EMAIL'];
                $direccion      = $fila['DIRECCION'];

                $contador++;
            }

        ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2 class="text-center all-tittles">listado de proveedores</h2>

        <div class="div-table">
            <div class="div-table-row div-table-head">
                <div class="div-table-cell">Código</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Ruc</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Razon Social</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Telefono</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Direccion</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Email</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Pais</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Ciudad</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Actualizar</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Eliminar</div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $codigo;?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $ruc?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $rsocial?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $telefono?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $direccion?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $email?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $pais?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell"><?php echo $ciudad?></div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">
                    <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="zmdi zmdi-refresh"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Si podés hacerlo, pero necesitás agregarle css para darle forma de tabla. La alternativa mas simple es usar un framework como bootstrap y su sistema de grillas.

Comment: Te sale solo el ultimo registro porque no tienes un ciclo que repita la acción y traiga todos los registros.

Comment: Hay que saber diferenciar entre la visualización y la lógica de negocios. Que solo te salga un registro no tiene nada que ver con que uses `div` o `tr` o que saques los datos por consola.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás ejecutando el `while` antes de imprimir los `div`, por eso las variables se sobreescriben y al terminar el ciclo quedan con los valores de última fila recuperada, tu código debería funcionar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2 class="text-center all-tittles">listado de proveedores</h2>

        <div class="div-table">
            <div class="div-table-row div-table-head">
                <div class="div-table-cell">Código</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Ruc</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Razon Social</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Telefono</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Direccion</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Email</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Pais</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Ciudad</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Actualizar</div>
                <div class="div-table-cell">Eliminar</div>
            </div>
           <?php 
           $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $contador = 0;

            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $codigo         = $fila['CODIGO'];
                $pais           = $fila['PAIS'];
                $ciudad         = $fila['CIUDAD'];
                $ruc            = $fila['RUC'];
                $rsocial        = $fila['RAZONSOCIAL'];
                $telefono       = $fila['TELEFONO'];
                $email          = $fila['EMAIL'];
                $direccion      = $fila['DIRECCION'];

                $contador++;
                echo '<div class="div-table-row">';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$codigo.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$ruc.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$rsocial.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$telefono.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$direccion.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$email.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$pais.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">'.$ciudad.'</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="zmdi zmdi-refresh"></i></button>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="div-table-cell">';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></button>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

        ?>
```

No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar o al menos darte una idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, gracias

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado. Solo para aclarar: El problema no tuvo que ver con el uso de los elementos `div` o `tr` sino con la lógica de ejecutar el ciclo completo antes de imprimir los elementos.